# mysql query with multiple left join in 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a search query which will retrieve information from 3 tables i made the query so it retrieve the information from 2 tables and i don't know if i can combine the third one or not

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
INNER JOIN terms
ON articles.ArticleID = terms.RelatedID AND terms.TermType = 'article'
```

the third query is

```
SELECT * FROM categories where CategoryID in (something)
```

something is a filed in the articles tables which have value like '3,5,8'

i want do this 2 queries into 1 query and i don't know if it can be done by 1 query or not

Comment: Is there a field in the categories table that matches a field in the articles or terms tables?  You will need one to join them.

Comment: @Tom the article table have a field ArticleCategories which have this value '3,5,8' and those are Categories ID's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without looking at your schema (which would be helpful) and some sample data try this query

```
SELECT *
FROM categories,articles
INNER JOIN terms
ON (articles.ArticleID = terms.RelatedID AND terms.TermType = 'article')
WHERE
FIND_IN_SET(categories.CategoryID,articles.categories)
```

here is the definition for `FIND_IN_SET()`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly. Looks like you have multiple categories for each article with the Category IDs all stored as a concatenated string.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM articles A
INNER JOIN terms T on A.ArticleID = T.RelatedID AND T.TermType = 'article'
LEFT JOIN categories C on C.CategoryID IN (3,5,8 OR A.CategoryIDs)
GROUP BY C.CategoryName
```

You want to LEFT JOIN since you may or may not have multiple categories, you can group by Categories to get disticnt category article pairs and CONCAT() to recombine article records as needed.

Comment: [depending on how big those tables are] You probably want to make sure you have indexes setup for each of those fields in your joins. The field with IDs [3,5,8] may still cause a seek. I definitely recommend normalizing that data in to a simple Article_Category table and indexing that.